# ExtJS Store reader.read not found

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonp, extjs4.1

I have this store:

```
Ext.define("App.store.units.MyStore", {

    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: "App.model.units.MyModel",

    model: "App.model.units.MyModel",
    id:'myStore',
    pageSize:10,
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: urls.MyUrl+"/search",
        limitParam: 'undefined',
        startParam: 'offSet',
        pageParam: 'undefined',
        extraParams: {
            searchString: 'a'
        },
        reader: {
            root: 'results.results',
            totalProperty: 'numFound',
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

The request works and I get the expected response.

For some reason, now I get this in the browser:

```
reader.read is not a function
```

I do not understand where the problem lies, because yesterday everything worked just fine(I know how this sounds, but I really don't know what's different).

Any suggestions that might help?

**EDIT** Here is also the (dynamic) definition of the model:

```
function(config){
    try{
        console.log("INIT MODEL");
    Ext.define("App.model.units.MyModel", {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: config
    });
    } catch(err){
        console.log("Error");
    }
}
```

This function is run *before* the store is created and the `config` object is an `array` of `{name: 'value'}` items.

I don't know what is wrong. Now everything seems to run good in Firefox, but IE8 still has that error(event with the `type:'json'` in the reader). I think the reader isn't instatiated right in IE8, but I can't check it, since objects aren't displayed right in its console(or I don't have the knowledge to do so). Why doesn't the same javascript code run as it should?

**LATER EDIT** For some reason, I get the `reader` only sometimes created. This is the problem. Sometimes it's just an object, not a needed `reader`. This happens also in Firefox. There doesn't seem to be any pattern.

Comment: This seems to me like a model-related problem. Try replacing the `model:` reference with a simple `fields: [...]` declaration, and see if the store loads successfully. Also, please post your code for `App.model.units.MyModel`.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov It is not about the model. The model is defined dynamically and the fields received are among the ones defined in the model. I am absolutely sure about this. After I have made `refresh` a few times and changed some `console.log()`, everything seems to be fine in Firefox(but still, I don't know why). IE8 still displays a similar error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I’m just asking because I’ve tried your code in JSFiddle, and it gave me the same error until I put in a `fields` declaration. I vaguely remember something similar from my own experience. The problem might not be with the model itself, but with how the reader is connected to it. Other than that, try breaking on your store’s `beforeload` and manually inspecting `store.getProxy().getReader()` to see if there’s anything funny there.

Comment: Also try setting `model` directly on your reader (in addition to the store), just in case.

Comment: A shot in the dark: missing `type` config in your reader?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov When I get the reader as you suggested, there are only the two fields I provide in the store and another one: `applyDefaults: true`. Shouldn't it be a bigger object?

Comment: @Izhaki OK, now it seems to be working in Firefox(could have been the missing `type` or it's just hazard), but IE8 still displays the error. Any other idea?

Comment: @Dragos: yes it should. This means that `Proxy` does not initialize the `reader` properly from config. I can’t tell why this happens, although I do stumble upon such errors from time to time, they are usually solved by hooking up some `model` somewhere :) Your best bet is to manually dig through the source code — http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Proxy2.html#Ext-data-proxy-Proxy — and see why `setReader` does not get called.

Comment: Mispelling? `requires` instead of `require`?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov With the `type: 'json'` property suggested by Izhaki, the reader gets now created(at least in Firefox). How do I get this fixed in IE8?

Comment: So I take it `requires` didn't do the trick?

Comment: @Izhaki I don't know if it was a typo or not, but changing it didn't make a difference. So, I'm stuck in the same situation.

Comment: I suspect the issue is not within this code. Could you please post the (dynamic) definition of the model?

Comment: You've included the definition of `FI.model.units.InstallBaseModel`, but where's the definition of `App.model.units.MyModel`? Or is your first bit of code is a modified one?

Comment: @Izhaki Sorry, fixed it. It was a typo, I've tried to simplify the names a bit :D.

Comment: maybe this  [sencha post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?154088-4.0.6-7-Proxy-reader-uses-wrong-model-to-read-response) can help ..

Comment: @sunny They do not seem to be related. My reader object is not being created for some reason.

Comment: @Dragos I have the same problem. Have you found anything?

Comment: @mik I don't remember exactly, but I think I solved it by moving the proxy to the model. I know it doesn't make any sense, but I am 100% sure I managed to solve some problem by doing this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem. This is what helped:

```
Ext.require('App.model.units.MyModel');
//or any other model you use in your store
```

put it somewhere **before** you create your store and it works!

Answer (score 0):

the requires config is an Array as stated in ExtJS docs:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I deleted my store fields. I had this for grid...

**grid**

```
            columns: [
                {header: "Status", width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'partystatus'},
                {header: "Name", width: 160, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'partyname'},
                {header: "Fathersname", width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'fathersname'},
                {header: "Grandfather", width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'grandfather'},
                {header: "Type", width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'partytype'}
            ],
```

and the following for store :

**store**

```
    fields: [
        {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'age', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'eyeColor', type: 'string'}
    ],
```

I simply removed the store fields thinking they were redundant, but i got that error instead.